# Как в MySQL добавить одно слово?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как добавить одно слово в определённые поля. Именно добавить в начале, не удаляя существующей информации полей.

Слово одно и тоже для всех полей. Информация в полях разная.

Comment: [`update your_table set your_field = concat('word', your_field)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) - так пойдет?

Comment: Ага, супер. Спасибо. А как теперь заглавную букву у теперь второго слова убрать?))))

Answer (score 2):

Данный запрос добавляет "NEW_STRING" в начало `column` и первую букву старого `column` переводит в нижний регистр.

```
update `table` set `column` = concat('NEW_STRING', concat(lower(left(`column`,1)),substr(`column`,2)));
```