# MySQL Как убрать все заглавные, кроме первой?

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL Как убрать все заглавные, кроме первой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в MySQL добавить одно слово?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466347/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-mysql-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be)

Comment: Двоечники выполняют домашнее задание?

Answer (score 3):

думаю это будет так

```
UPDATE tablisa
SET pole1 = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(pole1, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(pole1, 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Или так

```
concat(upper(mid(pole,1,1)), lower(mid(pole,2)))
```

Comment: Старайтесь давать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.